# How to handle SQL errors that are not handled by the try/catch block and result in System.TypeInitializationException?

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is a windows forms app. Below code is of a static class that tests db connectivity. `Test1.test` is invoked in the page load method.

```
public static class Test1
    {
       static string cStr = "Data Source=svrname;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=true";
       public static bool test{ get; } = chkDb();


        private static bool chkDb()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cStr ))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1;", connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This code usually works file. But if I enter an invalid dbname then it gives the below unhandled exception which seems to bypass the catch block. Similar thing happens when an invalid windows user tries to open the app.

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
> 'Project1.Test1' threw an exception.'
>
> Inner Exception:
> SqlException: Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login.
> The login failed. Login failed for user 'DOMAINXYZ\User1'.

How can I handle this exception? I have tried catching Exception, SqlException but none seem to work.

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to have this as a static property (or at all). The state of the database can change *at any time* and isn't under the control of your code. It answering `true` doesn't tell you that the database is *still* going to be available when you try to use it. It answering `false` tells you it wasn't available 5ms ago, but nothing about whether it's now available.

Comment: Non-trivial static initializers are evil, avoid them like the plague. This is one example of why you'd want to. There is no good reason to have a static initializer here; just make it a regular instance with a regular method and call it in your startup code. This does not answer the question of why this code fails (I don't think it should, actually, so this *might* be a bug in the JIT, or it might be some subtle detail of static initialization where this is actually the expected outcome), but it's always better to avoid having to ask such questions in the first place.

Comment: So if I want to read some values from db table only once when the static class is used, and then reuse then what is the way?

Comment: Prefer instances to statics; if you can centralize access (like, it's only used in one form, or one data access layer class) make it an instance field there and initialize things in the (non-static!) constructor, a separate method that's only called once, or use `Lazy`. You can pass instances around to those methods that need them, and only those (dependency injection). If you *must* have it as a static, stick to `Lazy`; this makes the time where the retrieval happens predictable, and exceptions can be caught in the calling code.

Comment: This particular method for testing if a DB is available doesn't need either a static property or `Lazy`; it could be a regular method of a static class. Having the connection string as a constant in a class is probably not what you'll end up with in production, as typically you'd want it to be configurable; given that, a method that takes the string as a parameter is more obvious.

Comment: I have couple of more methods that are static and do db calls to query a table just once. Pls can you point me to article on the concept of lazy as it will be usefull for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce the TypeInitializationException. Which framework version are you using? Or had you oversimplified your class so that it doesn't reproduce the error anymore?

Comment: It's the same code that gives the error. I'm using latest framework, specifically what do you want? I will check it when I login back into my system.

Comment: "using latest framework", Can you specify that, and give the number of the current latest framework, so any one who reads this on a later moment has an exact reference.  BTW: I had no problems using .NET Framework 4.8, After the timeout (because `srvname` could not be found, a `False` was returned.

Comment: @Luuk thanks:) I've tried it with 4.7.2, same result as yours.

Comment: Please call `Test1.test` from the form load event. Note: please ensure that you have placed a valid server name and an invalid database name. Let me know.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Correct me please if I'm wrong, but imho the autoproperty will have a `private static readonly <somebackingfield> = chkDb();`. So that could throw a TypeInitializationException without try/catch in chkDb.

Comment: @variable Did you try to put a breakpoint in `chkDb` to see where it get's called from? Luuk and myself are trying to reproduce the error without any success.

Comment: @Steeeve  You are correct.  I thought that was a normal getter, but it actually initializes the baking field in a static constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A complete repro:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bool b = Test1.test;
            textBox1.Text = b.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Test1.error;
        }
    }

    public static class Test1
    {
        static string cStr = "Data Source=svrname;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=true";
        public static bool test { get; } = chkDb();
        public static string error;

        private static bool chkDb()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cStr))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1;", connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

This was tested with .NET Framework 4.8, on Windows 10

If I change servername to a reachable server, the result is:
[image]

And, if I also change the `Initial Catalog` to an existing one, the first textBox gets the value `True` (and the 2nd textBox stays empty).

EDIT:
When I move 3 lines from `Form1` to `Form1_Load`:

```
       public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool b = Test1.test;
            textBox1.Text = b.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Test1.error;
        }
```

The results do not change.

Comment: Can you try running `bool b = Test1.test;` in the form load event please? I don't have access to my computer right now but will compare the code later.

Comment: I doubt it makes any difference, but please move the test code in form_load. You will have probably another synchronizationcontext after the form is loaded. I don't have an SQL server to play with...

Comment: Added the (requested) change.

Comment: @variable it's your turn ;) Thanks, Luuk!

Answer (score 0):

That will check the database connectivity only once, at class load time.  To move the check out of the type initializer, write it like this:

```
    public static bool test 
    { 
        get
        {
            return chkDb();
        }
    }
```

or make it a method instead of a property.

And the catch block will catch the exception.  You're probably just debugging and seeing a first chance exception.

Comment: I have made it a method to resolve this issue. I have seen such issue for the first time that the catch is unable to catch an exception.

Comment: Good.  It really should be a method.

Comment: What do you mean by first chance exception please?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: Ok so you mean to say that this is a debugger setting and that in production this issue will never arise? Also, can you tell me if it is a default debugger setting to not catch the above exception?

Comment: This doesn't address the TypeInitializationException I'm interested in.

Comment: Just guessing since it didn't repro.